# Mysql2 UPDATE query is taking too much time to update row

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql2

I am updating a row in MySQL database using `UPDATE` keyword (in an express server using `mysql2`). If the data I am using to update and the data in the row are same then it is taking time as usual. But if I update the table with different data then it takes longer time. There is my code below.

```
    public update = async (
    obj: TUpCred,
    ): Promise<ResultSetHeader> => {
        const sql = 'UPDATE ?? SET ? WHERE ?';

        const values = [obj.table, obj.data, obj.where];
        const [data] = (await this.connection.query({
            sql,
            values,
        })) as TResultSetHeader;

    return data;
    };
```

Then this query takes so long time. Usually it is taking `4` - `6` seconds but sometimes it even takes `10` to `15` seconds to update. The same happens with `INSERT` query. But other queries like `SELECT` is taking normal time to execute.

Comment: There's not enough information here to begin debugging. Normally, there should be no difference in those query executions. Do you have any triggers configured? What indexes do you have? What does your JS code actually look like?

Comment: @Phil check this out now

Comment: *`const sql = 'UPDATE ?? SET ? WHERE ?';`* ??? Do you want the SQL code fragments to be inserted instead of `?` placeholders? It shouldn't work..